# Auto click a hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, jquery

How do I automatically click a Hyerlink or LinkButton using jQuery

```
<asp:Hyperlink id="ttt" PostBackUrl="Hut.htm">Click</asp:Hyperlink>or<asp:LinkButton id="ttt" PostBackUrl="Hut.htm">Click</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943397/linkbutton-does-not-invoke-on-click , by the same person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the click event on a LinkButton (renders a html link) will not have much effect unless you have manually defined a javascript click event on it.

You need to execute the content in the href attribute (*javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$phContent$ttt", "", true, "", "", false, true))*):

> `eval($("a[id*='ttt']").attr("href"))`

The code above will evaluate the javascript code in the href attribute and execute it.

Comment: This does not work in many cases. If there is a return statement in the href, it fails. It also fails when "this" is used

Comment: That's true but I don't think ASP.NET generates a return statement or uses this in the href attribute when it renders a LinkButton.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [jQuery click()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click) function without any arguments to simulate a users click.

The only tricky part with asp.net controls is the ID will be some unwieldy generated ID like ctr_00_0001 so you'll have to use a class to target the button:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="ttt" PostBackUrl="Hut.htm" CssClass="myButton">Click</asp:LinkButton>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('.myButton').click();
```

Comment: How can I do it if this button is inside a ContentPage and using the Id and not the class?

Comment: @Hitz id='ttt" will no longer exists when asp:LinkButton rendered. so use CssClass. and what is the problem if it is inside Content page?

Comment: Try it at your end giving even the class. Keep  the LinkButton in Content Page and access it from MasterPage using class selector. It does not get clicked.

Comment: Master/Content Page doesn't matter as jquery runs client side. All jQuery sees is a single HTML document.  Did you surround the jQuery code with a $(document).ready()?