# jQuery: trigger <asp:LinkButton> click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, click

i need to trigger the click of an `<asp:LinkButton>`.

**Example1**

The following thing is working:

```
<asp:Button ID="myBtn" runat="server" />

$("#myBtn").trigger("click");
```

**Example2**

Now the same thing with the LinkButton is **not** working:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myBtn" runat="server" />

$("#myBtn").trigger("click");
```

I need to **trigger the click event of an asp:LinkButton**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `CssClass` property to your `LinkButton` and use that as your selector.

Other answers have suggested using ASP.NET `ClientID` to get the rendered ID of the `LinkButton`, which is fine, but this means you have to have your script inline in the page, and the script will only work for this 1 button.

Using a class means you can have multiple elements triggering the same event, and it means you don't need to use inline server-side code to get it to work.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myBtn" runat="server" CssClass="myLink" />

$(".myLink").trigger("click");
```

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer? It works for a Button, not for a LinkButton

Answer (score 23):

Instead of

```
$("#myBtn").trigger("click");
```

Try this

```
eval($("#myBtn").attr('href'));
```

See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/943441/1207991

Comment: @Spudley I had the same question as the original post and my web guru friend mentioned that eval() was bad as well but the other answers didn't actually work for me.

Something like this will work instead to mimick what the eval is doing with the href javascript that gets added by the LinkButton: `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("#<%= myBtn.ClientID %>", "", true, "SearchValidation", "", false, true));` using the correct validation group (among other things).

Comment: You shouldn't use eval() with linkbutton, or you will loose viewstate data. I've used it in a projects and it gave me quite a headache until I discovered. To preserve the viewstate on postback, you cant use eval.

Answer (score 1):

You're giving same `ID` to both of them which don't work.Try to change it.

If you're using master page then use as shown below:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#<%=myBtn.ClientID%>").click(function () {
              $('#<%=hyperlinkID.ClientID%>').trigger('click');
          });
  </script>
```

If you're don't use master page then use the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myBtn").click(function () {
             $('#hyperlinkID').trigger('click');
         });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use eval() because of security leaks and vulnerability. Best way to do this is with using of native js click event like that.

```
$('[selector]')[0].click();
```

in your case

```
$("#myLink")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line

```
$("#<%= myBtn.ClientID %>").trigger("click");
```